# search multiple words and expressions in a flowdocument wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, text, richtextbox, flowdocument

I'm working on a textanalysis tool and I would love loop through the whole text with multiple searchexpressions at the same time. What would be the right approach? This is the code I have for one search word.

```
        String search = "FINDME" ;

        TextPointer text = rtfMain.Document.ContentStart;

        for (TextPointer position = rtfMain.Document.ContentStart;
        position != null && position.CompareTo(rtfMain.Document.ContentEnd) <= 0;
        position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward))
        {
            if (position.CompareTo(rtfMain.Document.ContentEnd) == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            String textRun = position.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            StringComparison stringComparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture;
            Int32 indexInRun = textRun.IndexOf(search, stringComparison);

            if (indexInRun >= 0)
            {
                position = position.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun);
                if (position != null)
                {
                    TextPointer nextPointer = position.GetPositionAtOffset(search.Length);

                    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(position, nextPointer);
                    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty,
                                  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));
                    ResultList.Add(textRange.Text);
                }
            }
        }
```

What's the right approach for this? 
When one word has done searching the text, I need to automatically move to the next word and loop through the text again. 
Do I make a List or fill an array with those search words? Can anybody guide me in the right direction? Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is really time-taking, unproductive to search strings without regular expressions.

Use regular expressions. This is very powerful tool. Start read an article - "Search strings using Regular Expressions" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms228595.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure that I understood right your probem:

*You've got a TEXT in whih you are looking for many WORD(S).*

Doesen't really mtter in which collection you store these WORDS(array, list...)

As you will do many lookus in the TEXT I'll suggest you to use the [KMP algorith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) to only lookup in the rrys containing the first letter of a given WORD (the one you will be sarching for at a given time).

The preprocession of the KMP will be quite time costing, but the more WORDS you will search for in the text, the more efficient it will become.